# how to use python xlsxwriter to conditionally format on cell value

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I would like to output conditional formatted Excel worksheets where for each column the condition is dependent on the value in the first row.  Using the shown data frame cells A2, A4, B3, B4, C4, C5, D4, and E4 will be highlighted red.

```
import xlsxwriter

data = [
    [1, 1, 5, 'A', 1],
    [1, 4, 4, 'B', 0],
    [2, 1, 5, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 5, 'A', 1],
]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('testout.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

formatyellow = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'#F7FE2E'})
formatred = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'#FF0000'})
i=0
for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    print (row)
    print (row_data)
    ws.write_row(row, 0, row_data)
    i += 1

ws.conditional_format(0,1,4,5, {'type':'text',
                      'criteria':'containing',
                      'value':'B',
                      'format':formatyellow})
ws.conditional_format(0,1,4,5, {'type':'cell',
                      'criteria':'==',
                      'value':'A$1',
                      'format':formatred})
```

This is what I'm getting:
[image: Getting this:]

This is what I'm trying to get:
[image: Going for this:]

Is there a way of getting this done using xlsxwriter?

Comment: Two things. First, I cannot run your code without adding `wb.close()` to the end.  Second, I generate a [different output](http://imgur.com/a/SNR44) from your code then what you have shown. Can you update your post to include more information about your system? (i.e. python version, xlsxwriter version, and os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to produce the desired result after changing the indexing in `ws.conditional_format`. Remember that `xslxwriter` uses zero indexing, so `row=0`, `col=0` corresponds to cell `A0`. Also, I had to add `wb.close()` to the end of the fuction

```
import xlsxwriter

data = [
    [1, 1, 5, 'A', 1],
    [1, 4, 4, 'B', 0],
    [2, 1, 5, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 5, 'A', 1],
]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('testout.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

formatyellow = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'#F7FE2E'})
formatred = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'#FF0000'})
i=0
for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    print (row)
    print (row_data)
    ws.write_row(row, 0, row_data)
    i += 1

ws.conditional_format(1,0,3,4, {'type':'text',   #Start from row 1 ("B") and column 0 (1)
                      'criteria':'containing',
                      'value':'B',
                      'format':formatyellow})
ws.conditional_format(1,0,3,4, {'type':'cell',
                      'criteria':'==',
                      'value':'A$1',
                      'format':formatred})

wb.close()
```

Output:

[image: produced output]